# I am wondering why my output for Int for Expenses and Difference isn't coming out right?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am wondering why my output is not coming out the way I thought it should.  It is only for those two integers.
The first two are coming out correctly.

**This is my code:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BarkingLot {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner Scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x = 20;
    int y = 25;
    int Small = 0;
    int Large = 0;
    int Revenue = ((Small * x) + (Large * y));
    int Food = ((Small + Large) * (2));
    int Facility = 30;
    int Expenses = (Food + Facility);
    int Difference = (Revenue - Expenses);

    System.out.println("Enter number of small dogs: ");
    Small = Scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter number of large dogs: ");
    Large = Scanner.nextInt();

    if ((Small + Large) <= 8) {
      System.out.println("Revenue is " + ((Small * x) + (Large * y)));
      System.out.println("Food = " + ((Small + Large) * (2)));
      System.out.println("Expenses = " + (Food + Facility));
      System.out.println("Difference = " + (Revenue - Expenses));

    } else
      System.out.println("The number of dogs has exceeded the facility limit.");
  }
}
```

Comment: Well what did you expect, and what did you get? It would also really help if you'd indent your code to make it more readable, and follow normal Java naming conventions.

Comment: Your code does exactly what you wrote, you're probably misunderstanding it. Please post what you expected and what you're getting.

Comment: `Expenses` and `Difference` never change after theyre initially assigned. Move the assignments after `Small` &  `Large` have been read if you want those variables to reflect the new values read from the user input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You scan for the values of `small` and `large` **AFTER** computing the values of `Expenses` and `Difference`. Try reordering them, like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BarkingLot {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner Scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x = 20;
    int y = 25;
    int Small = 0;
    int Large = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter number of small dogs: ");
    Small = Scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter number of large dogs: ");
    Large = Scanner.nextInt();

    int Revenue = ((Small * x) + (Large * y));
    int Food = ((Small + Large) * (2));
    int Facility = 30;
    int Expenses = (Food + Facility);
    int Difference = (Revenue - Expenses);

    if ((Small + Large) <= 8) {
      System.out.println("Revenue is " + ((Small * x) + (Large * y)));
      System.out.println("Food = " + ((Small + Large) * (2)));
      System.out.println("Expenses = " + (Food + Facility));
      System.out.println("Difference = " + (Revenue - Expenses));

    } else
      System.out.println("The number of dogs has exceeded the facility limit.");
  }
}
```

---

Also, variable names in java should not be capitalized, to prevent confusion with classes. Do you see how the `Scanner` CLASS is shadowed (uses the same name as) by the `Scanner` variable?

Remember: classes - capitalized. Everything else (methods, fields, variables), lowercase.

Comment: This is interesting. It worked perfectly!  I appreciate the help, my friend.

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing `Food` from the variables `Small` and `Large` BEFORE you've actually gotten these values from the user.

```
System.out.println("Enter number of small dogs: ");
Small = Scanner.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter number of large dogs: ");
Large = Scanner.nextInt();
int Food = ((Small+Large)*2);
```

will then set up `Food` correctly. For your print-outs, then make sure you are using the variable itself (i.e. `Food`), not re-computing what the variables stand for (i.e. `((Small+Large)*2)`).